Bulk update in PostgreSQL with psycopg2 doesn't work
def update_database(self, results):
    try:
        length = len(self.unique_ids)
        update_data = [(self.unique_ids[i], results[i]) for i in range(length)]
        query = """
                UPDATE public.post_data AS p
                SET content = t.content
                FROM (VALUES %s)
                AS t (unique_id, content)
                WHERE p.unique_id = t.unique_id;
                """

        template = '(%s, %s)'
        execute_values(self.cursor, query, update_data, template=template)
        self.conn.commit()
        logging.info("Successfully Updated")


    except Exception as error:
        logging.warning(f"Update Error -> {error}")

    finally:
        self.conn.close()
        self.cursor.close()

This is the code i execute for bulk update. When i run the query separately in query console it works just fine, doesn't properly work this way though.

What does the Postgres log show when you execute the above?

Change self.cursor to self.conn.cursor().
Even better, use with to ensure the connection is closed after the transaction.
like:
with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
    execute_values(cursor, query, update_data, template=template)
    self.conn.commit()
    logging.info("Successfully Updated")

